# Dotnetnuke - Display image outside portal folder

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a site with a lot of images. I resized those images and store them in a folder of the root (Folder to deploy site). But the image in that folder is not showing on the browser. I think that is permission problem. Any one have solution to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to manipulate the images with any of the portal administrative tools, but you will be able to link to them.  You'll have to add links manually.

So, if you put your images in a folder called myimages in the root of your install ... a url to image1.png would be http://myste.com/myimages/image1.pn.

Comment: Dear Joe.I have linked the image as your guide but the image is not display at all. This is my image url: http://dnndev.me/vnp_caching/150_150/20150513_213907.jpg